# Does sigmoid_cross_entropy produce the mean loss over the whole batch?

Tags: tensorflow, classification, multilabel-classification, cross-entropy, sigmoid

I have a multi-label classification task and there are 6 labels. Any sample may have none or some labels to be 1. I have use the loss in tensorflow:

```
self.loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(self.labels, self.logits)
```

Every time a batch (1000) of samples come in, the loss calculated.

But I am not sure whether the loss is **the average of the log loss of each predicted column.** If it is not, how can I modify the loss to be the **mean column-wise log loss** mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's not *exactly* the mean, or, more precisely, not *always* the mean.

[`tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sigmoid_cross_entropy) has a `reduction` argument (by default equal to `Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS`) and a `weights` argument (by default `1.0`):

> `weights`: Optional `Tensor` whose rank is either 0, or the same rank as `labels`, and must be broadcastable to `labels` (i.e., all dimensions must be either 1, or the same as the corresponding losses dimension).
>
> `reduction`: Type of reduction to apply to loss.

There are several types of reduction:

- `Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS` computes the `SUM` divided by number of non-zero weights.
- `Reduction.SUM` is the weighted sum.
- `Reduction.MEAN` is the weighted mean.
- `Reduction.NONE` means no reduction (the result shape is the same as input).

As you can see, the result depends on *both of them*. Yes, when both have default values, the loss equals to the mean. But if one of them is non-default, e.g., one of the weights is zero, the mean will be computed over non-zero weights, not over the whole batch.

Comment: Thanks. If there is no none value in both logits and labels, the loss shall be the mean of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any loss in tensorflow produce mean over the complete batch. So, if batchwise loss is as follows

```
[2, 3, 1, 4]
```

Net loss will `2.5`